# Derivation of the transfer function form with the system type number included

Tags: control-system, transfer-function

A transfer function is derived from an ODE with the Laplace transform as following...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Some times though there is a different form of the transfer function, one that includes the system type number \$l\$.

[image]

How is that form derived? As I have listed the way we go from an ODE to a transfer function, how is the system type number came to be included in it? 
g

Comment: does this help? http://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/ode/laplace/solve/solve.html

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 This is an example of using Laplace transform, I don't see how it can be relevant here. Although thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: ok then you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform_applied_to_differential_equations too?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Suffice to say that I have 3 Control Engineering books open in front of me right now and 10 tabs in the browser. I have searched everywhere. This is not the standard derivation of the transfer function. The standard derivation is very easy. The only thing I don't understand is the case where the system type number appears in a particular form. I don't ask regarding the Laplace transform or the math included.

Comment: The second TF is the forward path of the system. This is how type number is defined.

Comment: Why did the m and n subscripts change between b and a. Sorry I was just glancing through it and this confused me. (First line of math and 2nd line of math).

Comment: @Andyaka You are right...I hadn't noticed it. I took that picture from two different sections of a book. I will find the correct one and edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

The type number is the number of pure integrators in the forward path, \$\small G(s)\$, of a closed loop system. This is equivalent to saying the number of 'free' \$ s\$ terms in the denominator of \$\small G(s)\$ . Alternatively, the number of poles of \$\small G(s)\$ at the origin.

It can easily be shown that the type number defines the steady state response of the closed loop system to various deterministic input signals. Thus a type 1 system will have zero SS error to a step input, a type 2 will have zero SS error to a ramp input; a type 3 to a parabola etc.

Hence if the CLTF is \$ \frac{G(s)}{1+G(s)H(s)}\$, then the type number is the number of denominator free \$s\$ terms in \$\small G(s)\$. Note, type number is not determined by the open loop TF, \$\small G(s)H(s)\$, unless the system is unity feedback.